# Jmeter - extend http test recorder

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is it possible to extend Jmeter http script test recorder?

Would like to edit recorded requests automatically instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is an open source software distributed under [Apache License 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) so you can add whatever functionality you need.

JMeter source code is available via [Git](https://github.com/apache/jmeter) and [SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/) repositories and you can find the official manual on extending JMeter at [How to Write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf)

If you'll create something very useful for others I believe it would be a good idea to contribute it back, send a message to [Apache JMeter Developer](http://jmeter.apache.org/mail2.html#JMeterDev) for further instructions on how you can add your code to JMeter.

---

If your idea of "automatic editing" is about adding missing automated correlation and you need the functionality right away you can consider and alternative recording service instead of JMeter's built-in proxy, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for details.

Comment: Can you provide a example how to start with it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Look at [this one](https://www.smartmeter.io/quick-guide#toc-how-to-record-test-script)

Comment: I'm looking to extend Jmeter by myself. Don't want to use any third party tool.